Keep/Build a map when doing multiple pandas groupby operations
Imagine a process, where we do several pandas groupbys.
We start with a df like so:
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
np.random.seed(1)

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'id': np.arange(10),
    'a': np.random.randint(1, 10, 10),
    'b': np.random.randint(1, 10, 10),
    'c': np.random.randint(1, 10, 10)
})
df
Out[23]: 
   id  a  b  c
0   0  2  8  2
1   1  8  8  9
2   2  7  2  9
3   3  3  8  4
4   4  5  1  9
5   5  6  7  8
6   6  3  8  4
7   7  5  7  7
8   8  3  2  6
9   9  5  1  2

We perform a groupby 'a' (The 'max' agg is just an example)
new_df = df.groupby('a').agg('max').reset_index()
Out[25]: 
   a  id  b  c
0  2   0  8  2
1  3   8  8  6
2  5   9  7  9
3  6   5  7  8
4  7   2  2  9
5  8   1  8  9

And I want to keep track of the original id to which group it belongs.
For example,
id 0 belongs to a = 2, 
1 to 8, 
2 to 7, 
(3, 6, 8) belongs to 3 
etc..

Afterword we perform another groupby:
new_df.groupby('b').agg('max').reset_index()
Out[28]: 
   b  a  id  c
0  2  7   2  9
1  7  6   9  9
2  8  8   8  9

Now we have a continued mapping,
Where
group a (2, 3, 8) belongs to group 8 (of b)
(5, 6) = 7
7 = 2

And this result in a long map where the original id:
0 => a = 2 => b = 8 (where b = 8 is the final group that interests me)
1 => a = 8 => b = 8
2 => a = 7 => b = 2

And so on..
Now I do this in order to reduce a lot of entities in my data so that I can group them in the same bucket somehow. And I need to map them from their original id to a new id, that is being represented after many iterations of groupby.
In the end I want to see something like so
Out[32]: 
   id  grp
0   0    8
1   1    8
2   2    2
3   3    8
4   4    7
5   5    7
6   6    8
7   7    7
8   8    8
9   9    7

again, because id=0 went to a=2 and a=2 went to b=8..
Any solution or suggestion will be most welcome. Even carrying the values in a column dedicated to this, with each group by.
And when we aggregate, we can do a set addition...

This looks to me like a graph problem. You could build a directed graph from successive groupby using networkx, then pair the roots/leaves of each subgraph:
import networkx as nx

G = nx.DiGraph()

ref = 'id'
cols = ['a', 'b']
for col in cols:
    tmp = df.groupby(ref, as_index=False)[[ref, col]].max()
    G.add_edges_from((((ref, r), (col, x))
                      for r, x in zip(tmp[ref], tmp[col])))
    ref = col

out = []
for c in nx.weakly_connected_components(G):
    H = G.subgraph(c)
    roots = [n for n, d in H.in_degree() if d==0]
    leaves = [n for n, d in H.out_degree() if d==0]
    out.extend([dict((r, l)) for r in roots for l in leaves])

out = (pd.DataFrame(out)
         .sort_values(by='id', ignore_index=True)
      )

Output:
   id  b
0   0  8
1   1  8
2   2  2
3   3  8
4   4  7
5   5  7
6   6  8
7   7  7
8   8  8
9   9  7

Graph:


Thank you very much mozway! I actually failed to model the problem correctly. I should have modeled it with graph from the get go. Instead of doing those groupbys, and find connections, I can do a Union Find after mapping all connections via graph.

Yes, if you can use a graph-only approach that's even better, glad it got you on the right track ;)

A pure pandas solution is going to use a sequence of join/merge/reindex operations. You'll need to manage the ordering of the transitions externally, but can land on a solution like:
from io import StringIO
from textwrap import dedent

buffer = StringIO(dedent('''
    id a  b  c
    0  2  8  2
    1  8  8  9
    2  7  2  9
    3  3  8  4
    4  5  1  9
    5  6  7  8
    6  3  8  4
    7  5  7  7
    8  3  2  6
    9  5  1  2
''').strip())

# ---

import pandas as pd
from itertools import pairwise

df = pd.read_csv(buffer, sep=r'\s+')

steps = ['id', 'a', 'b']
intermediates = {steps[0]: df[steps[0]].values}
for left, right in pairwise(steps):
    intermediates[right] = (
        df.groupby(left)[right].agg('max')
        .reindex(intermediates[left])
        .values
    )

final = pd.DataFrame(intermediates)
print(final)
#    id  a  b
# 0   0  2  8
# 1   1  8  8
# 2   2  7  2
# 3   3  3  8
# 4   4  5  7
# 5   5  6  7
# 6   6  3  8
# 7   7  5  7
# 8   8  3  8
# 9   9  5  7

To only get the first/last levels, you can:
final = pd.DataFrame({k: intermediates[k] for k in [steps[0], steps[-1]]})
print(final)
#    id  b
# 0   0  8
# 1   1  8
# 2   2  2
# 3   3  8
# 4   4  7
# 5   5  7
# 6   6  8
# 7   7  7
# 8   8  8
# 9   9  7

